# Angular ngOnInit - Refresh Needed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, ngoninit

I have a web application. In my right side bar i have 3 posts.
When i click on a post, i have a navigation:

```
    this.router.navigate(['../post', this.post.id]);
```

There a post profile component will take over.
This component has a function that calls a function from a service that gets my post with the specified id. Now i will see all the details of that post in my content area (left part of the screen). This function(that gets my post) is called only in ngOnInit on the Post Profile component.

If i click on another post from my right side bar, i can see the change in url but the function that gets my post is not called and the post details from my content area are not changed.
If i refresh the page now i can see the post that i want, everything works well.

I have .subscribe on my functions, if that helps.

I can't see the problem.

This is my PostProfileComponent

```
        constructor(postsService: PostsService, route: ActivatedRoute ) {
    this.postsService = postsService;

    this.routeSubscription = route.params
        .subscribe((params: any) => {
            this.postId = params['id'];
        });
}

public getPostById(id: any): void {
    this.postsService.getPostById(id)
        .map((response: Post) => {
            this.post = response;
            console.log(this.post);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            return error;
        })
        .subscribe();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPostById(this.postId);
}
```

Comment: You would really have to show your actual code, no one can guess how your code looks like. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Post Profile component's ngOnInit method you've to subscribe to the `ActivatedRoute` `params` Observable.

```
  subs1: Subscription;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.subs1 = this.route.params
         .subscribe((params: Params) => {
             const postId = params['id'] ? +params['id'] : '';
             if(postId){
                //  call the function (that gets the post)
             }
         });
  }
```

Comment: How do you know that OP's code does not look like this? The problem could be anywhere, that's why I asked for code. Maybe you are right tho, who knows.

Comment: I think he wants generic solution and that is what I've tried to give here. But, if @Marian gives us some of his implemented code then I'll  update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Marian, you're welcome. If my solution works then it would be helpful to others if you accepted my solution as correct answer.